# Prove that the irrationals are dense in the irrationals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble with this proof. I think I need to show that every neighborhood of an irrational number contains at lest one other irrational number. I'm getting lost in the notation.

Comment: $a$ irrational implies $a+1/n$ also irrational

Comment: Add to Angina's comment: for all $n\in\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Every set is dense in itself.

Comment: @SahibaArora: [That is not true.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense-in-itself) E.g., $\Bbb Z$ is not dense in itself, though it is a dense subset of itself. The two are not the same.

Comment: @AnginaSeng So I need to show that using a neighborhood around some irrational number?

Comment: What notation are you getting lost in?

Comment: I understand what the top comment means. Thanks by the way Angina Seng. I'm assuming that the proof requires more than that one line. So I need to start with the definition of a neighborhood and apply that to a irrational imples a + 1/n?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah, I thought OP meant dense subset of itself. Of course, I know it may not be true otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

A cardinality argument works. Any $\epsilon$-neighborhood of a point contains uncountably many points, whereas the rationals are countable. If any such neighborhood contains only rational numbers, its cardinality is at most countable, a contradiction.

To see that any neighborhood $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ contains uncountably many points, map it linearly to $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and apply the arctan function to map that interval to $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

Comment: So I need to do a proof by contradiction in the rationals to show the irrationals are dense in themselves? I'm sorry, this just seems so abstract. I'm having trouble visualizing it.

Comment: I am not appealing to any density results. The idea of this proof is that the set of irrational numbers is much "larger" in some sense than the set of rational numbers. Therefore, if an open neighborhood contained only rational numbers, it would be too small to actually be a neighborhood.

If this is a little past the material you have already learned, I would suggest using the top comment on your original post. $a$ irrational implies $a+\frac{1}{n}$ irrational for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so by making $n$ arbitrarily large, you can find irrational numbers arbitrarily close to $a$.

Comment: Yea, that might be a bit more than what I've learned. It does make sense though. Other than showing it in math notation. haha. So the top comment and showing that makes sense as well, but it comes down to the notation. So showing that would show that another irrational is in some neighborhood?

Answer (score 1):

Any set is dense in itself, as $\bar A\supset A$.

Comment: This does not answer the question. One must distinguish between being a dense subset of itself, which it is, and being a dense-in-itself set — one without isolated points — which is what is meant in this question.

Comment: I didn't see the words "dense-in-itself set" anywhere, but I'll take your word for it.  @Brian M.Scott

Comment: Sorry, I thought the way I worded it meant the same things.

Comment: Yeah because I had only been familiar with the one notion.  Like, $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ means $\bar{\Bbb Q}=\Bbb R$.  No worries.